# Trying to figure out how to run the code Standard Meta Language

Tags: sml, ml

I'm trying to figure out how to run the code Standard Meta Language:

```
smallest [5, ~4, 3]; returns ~4

fun smallest L =
    if null (tl L)
    then hd L
    else if hd L < smallest (tl L)
         then hd L
         else smallest (tl L);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need an SML interpretor, or compilor. There is multiple to choose from, but [SML/NJ](http://www.smlnj.org/) is most likely the most known/used.

Others include (but are not limited to) [Moscow ML](http://www.itu.dk/~sestoft/mosml.html) (MosML), [MLKit](http://www.itu.dk/research/mlkit/index.php/Main_Page) and [MLton](http://www.mlton.org/). Where MLKit and MLton are compilers and SML/NJ and MosML are interpreters.

The [wikipedia article on SML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_ML) is properly a good starting point for you to learn some more about SML.

Comment: @xprogrammerx: You will have to do this yourself by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend PolyML. It's got some of the better documentation for ML out there.